# Cross table LinqToSQL query WP7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

Basically, I have three tables, lets call them TableA, TableB and TableC.

Table A & B have two columns of interest, ID & Value. Table C has three columns, ID, A_ID and B_ID.

I'm looking to construct a LinqToSQL query that:

- Returns the Value from Tables A and B where Table C has a record containing both A & B's ID's

Example:

[image]

The returned records should be of a specific type:

```
public class RecordClass
{
    string A_Value;
    string B_Value;
    public RecordClass()
    {
        A_Value = "";
        B_Value == "":
    }
}
```

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want an inner join:

```
 var query = from a in tableA
             from b in tableB
             join c in tableC on new { A_ID = a.ID, B_ID = b.ID } 
                          equals new { c.A_ID, c.B_ID }
             select new RecordClass { A_Value = a.Value, B_Value = b.Value };
```

EDIT: Alternatively, if you've got your LINQ to SQL model wired up correctly, it could be much simpler:

```
var query = tableC.Select(c => new RecordClass { A_Value = c.A.Value,
                                                 B_Value = c.B.Value });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's close but it's complaining that 'an anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name' - referring to 'b.ID'. Also, TableC does not contain A_Value or B_Value, these are stored in the respective tables. TableC is really just a pairing table that pairs records from TableA with records from TableB (using their ID fields).

Comment: @user1567095: Fixed to use `A_Value` and `B_Value` in the join... but I'd assumed that `A_Value` and `B_value` in `TableC` were the IDs. I don't understand why you'd post the code that you have if it's inaccurate.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion I caused. For each record in Table C I'd like to use A_ID and B_ID (both stored in Table C) to lookup the records in Tables A and B that match those IDs. Also, upon execute I get this error 'The method 'Join' is not supported.

Comment: @user1567095: Okay, so it should be easy enough to change my code to use those properties. But I'm alarmed that `Join` isn't supported. That sounds very odd indeed... have you had other LINQ operations working correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have other LINQ queries working successfully. I am able to pull records from all tables successfully, even with filters and sorting. Your code is recognised and builds but complains at execution.

Comment: I've added an example of the table structure.

Comment: @user1567095: Okay - I've edited my answer with another option, depending on how you've got things wired up. I don't know why the join wouldn't work though...

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried it on another machine and it works. Time for a reinstall I think. Thanks very much for all your help!